# Else If Avoidance in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote the following sproc to search for a record and terminate at the table it cant find it with the hardcoded error message.

It works but I want it to be smarter. Any suggestion please.

---

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[dummy_test]

@ID NVARCHAR(50)

AS
BEGIN


Declare @TID Table (TID bigint not null)    
declare @TransId bigint     

-- Search for @TID
insert into @TID
Select TID from x..tables  where   EID = @ID 

Select @TransId = (select TID from @TID)

If not exists 
(select top 1 1  from x..table7  where TID = @TransId)
print 'B'
else
If not exists
(select top 1 1  from x..table6  where TID=  @TransId)
print 'C'
else

If not exists
(select top 1 1  from x..table0  where TID=  @TransId)
print 'D'
else

If not exists
(select top 1 1  from x..table1  where TID =  @TransId)
print 'E'
else

If not exists
(select top 1 1  from x..table2  where TID =  @TransId)
print 'F'
else

If not exists
(select top 1 1  from x..table3  where TID =  @TransId)
print 'G'

delete @TID


END
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what is meant by being smarter?

Comment: I think there should be a way to avoid the repetitive nested if else statement

Answer (score 0):

The only improvement I can suggest is to get rid of the Table variable in your code which is totally unnecessary and do something like....

```
declare @TransId bigint     

Select @TransId = TID from x..tables  where   EID = @ID
```

Other than the above code I don't think you can simplify the remaining code since it is checking for existence of the `@TransId` in different tables.